# Why is this short sample of sockets code producing corrupted files?

Tags: java, android, sockets, networking, tcp

I am trying to do something like in this first example of code below that is non-blocking but it gives corrupted files. The second example works fine but it is blocking, if you don't close the socket of output stream from the client side (other side), which is the other device this sever is connected to, then it will block and thread execution will not go any farther than that.

What is wrong with the first piece of code that causes it to produce corrupted files every time?

First example code, good idea but produces corrupted files;

```
 while(totalBytesRead < fileSizeFromClient){
            int bytesRemaining = fileSizeFromClient - totalBytesRead;
            int bytesRead = bufferedInputStream.read(buffer, totalBytesRead, bytesRemaining);
                            bufferedOutputStream.write(buffer, totalBytesRead, bytesRemaining);

            if(bytesRead == -1){
                break;
             }else{
                totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
            }
        }
```

Second example, code gets stuck; blocks. So I can't use this, as you have to kill the socket from the client side to get code execution to continue beyond these lines of code. But it produces perfect uncorrupted files.

```
  while((count = bufferedInputStream.read(buffer)) > 0){
        bufferedOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, count); 
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line writes all of the "remaining" bytes, even if only one byte was read, and also potentially writes something if `read` returned -1 signaling the end of input:

```
bufferedOutputStream.write(buffer, totalBytesRead, bytesRemaining);
```

To write only the bytes that were read, pass the number of bytes that were read as the third parameter.

```
    int bytesRead = bufferedInputStream.read(buffer, totalBytesRead, bytesRemaining);

    if (bytesRead == -1) {
        break;
     } else {
        bufferedOutputStream.write(buffer, totalBytesRead, bytesRead);
        totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
    }
```

There is no reason why the second code should block and this one not, though.

Also note that this way you are creating an in-memory copy of the data that you are transferring, which may occupy a lot of memory or make the program fail with `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if the buffer is not big enough. If that was not your intention you should use `0` instead of `totalBytesRead` as the array offset when reading and writing, and limit the number of bytes read to the size of the buffer. After these transformations the code would look like this:

```
    int bytesRead = bufferedInputStream.read(buffer);

    if (bytesRead == -1) {
        break;
     } else {
        bufferedOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
    }
```

As you can see, it is almost identical to your second example, which you say "blocks."

Comment: The offset arguments are wrong in both cases, and will cause the methods they are used in to throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: Whether or not that happens depends on the size of the buffer. If the OP wants to get an in-memory copy of the data read and written, this is one way to do it. But care *must* be taken to create a buffer big enough to hold the data that is transfered.

Comment: Whether or not that happens depends on the size of the buffer *and* the size of the file. Using `totalBytesRead` instead of zero is just a massive waste of the previous bytes in the buffer. Given a big enough file the code becomes entirely infeasible unless you use the entire buffer, via an offset of zero. It's pointless to defend this, it's just plain wrong, and another error in the OP's code that should have been picked up.

Comment: It is pointless only if the OP's intention is to not read the file entirely into memory. If the intention is to just pipe the data from one side to the next it is pointless to do it, and a waste of resources. But, if the file data is indeed needed in memory, for example for processing that takes place immediately afterwards, this way the file does not have to be read again. It's not my place to guess why/if the OP wants an in-memory copy of the data, I just noticed that their code produces one as a side effect.

Answer (score 1):

1. The test for `bytesRead == -1` should precede the write, not follow it.
2. The length argument for `write()` should be `bytesRead`.
3. The offset arguments for both `read()` and `write()` should be zero.